# I can't change the color of my links with CSS

Tags: css

This is my link:

```
<div id="yabnetwork">
    Bu site bir <a target="_blank" href="http://yusufalibozkir.com" title="Yusuf Ali Bozkir Network  <br/>Tel:.......... <br/>info@yusufalibozkir.com">YAB Network</a> urunudur.
</div>
```

My CSS styles for this div:

```css
#yabnetwork{
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:right;
}     

#yabnetwork a{
    color:red;
}
```

Why are my links not red? I can't change them.

Comment: All modern browsers have debugging tools allowing you to view elements. Use such tool to see what's going on with the anchor element and you'll most likely have your answer.

Comment: Not possible to figure out the root cause with this bit of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

```
#yabnetwork a{
    color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: i think yes, we need to use !important all times because default color of clicked link is dark blue, but i am not sure.

Comment: using `!important` is generally considered a bad thing. Yes, there are a few times when it is necessary, but in most cases it's not needed, and can cause other problems (eg styles set with `!important` can't be overridden by javascript code).

Comment: You don't need to use `!important`. Click links can be styled using the `:visited` psuedo class: `#yabnetwork a:visited { color: red; }`

Answer (score 5):

The first part of the a-tag seems to miss a closing bracket and a quote-mark.:

```
Bu site bir <a target="_blank" href="http://yusufalibozkir.com" title="Yusuf Ali Bozkir Network" > <br/>Tel:.......... <br/>info@yusufalibozkir.com">YAB Network</a> urunudur.
```

Two recommendations are to start using a text-editor with color-markup and run your code in the html-validator:
http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
a:link{

color:#00CC66;

text-decoration: none

}
a:visited{

color:#ff0000;

text-decoration: none

}
a:hover{color:#f00000;

text-decoration: none

}
a:active{color:#f00000;

text-decoration: none

}
```

Links can have different states:

- `a:link` --> default
- `a:visited` --> if the user already visited this page
- `a:hover` --> if the mouse cursor is over the link
- `a:active` --> if the link represents the page currently displayed

Comment: With the style attribute u can use CSS definitions right in the place where u need them.

Comment: use the style attribute: e.g.<a href="yourpage.com" target="_blank" style="a:link{color:#00CC66;text-decoration:none}">yourtext</a>

Answer (score 1):

It is red! If tags are closed properly and attributes ended with " as they should.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>link example</title>
<style type="text/css">
#yabnetwork a{
    color:red; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="yabnetwork">
    Bu site bir <a target="_blank" href="http://yusufalibozkir.com" title="Yusuf Ali Bozkir Network">  <br/>Tel:.......... <br/>info@yusufalibozkir.com">YAB Network</a> urunudur.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe you override the CSS rule somewhere? If yes, you might try !important as well:

```
#yabnetwork a{
    color:red !important; 
}
```